# How KSQL Windowed query works and maximum window size

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, ksqldb

I have two questions regarding querying in KSQL wrt queries that use windowing :

1. Let's say I have the following aggregation query :

   SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM testtopic_stream WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 30 DAYS) GROUP BY id;

Are the results of the aggregation above calculated by only using the new tick that comes in OR it actually will go through all the data for last 30 days and then perform the aggregation?

2. What is the maximum possible window size for queries? I see I am able to set up a window for even like 30 days and the query seems to work fine now. Is there a recommended maximum window size?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on `auto.offset.reset` strategy. If you set it to `"earliest"`, the query will consumer all data from the underlying stream/topic (note, that "all" means really all data that is stored in the topic, ie, it depends on topic retention setting how much data this will be). If you set the config to `"latest"` -- what is the default -- the query will only process data that is written by upstream producers after the query was started.

In both cases, the size of the window has no impact on what data will be processed.

There is no limit on the window size. You can pick any size you want. Note: for tumbling windows, a smaller window size in fact increases storage requirement while a larger window sizes reduces storage requirement because there are fewer windows that need to be maintained in parallel.

Comment: I see. So let's consider the classic example of word count. If I have a persistent query tracking word count for each word on the topic, each time new data flows into the topic, the updated word count is calculated as (previousWordCount from table + wordCount in current event), correct?

Comment: I guess you mean "continuous query" (not sure what a "persistent query" is). Beside this, correct. Depending if you specify a windowed aggregation of not, the count also either over all time, of further "grouped" into time-buckets following the window specification.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. If I have a hopping window of 1 minute, with an advance of 10 seconds, I get 6 different counts because of 60/10? Is it possible to get only one of these 6 different aggregates to be displayed in the query?

Comment: "If I have a hopping window of 1 minute, with an advance of 10 seconds, I get 6 different counts because of 60/10?" -- Correct. "Is it possible to get only one of these 6 different aggregates to be displayed in the query?" -- not sure what you mean... What is the use case? Wouldn't this be a tumbling window use case?

Comment: I am interested in tracking the rolling sum of a field for the last 60 seconds where every 10 seconds, the oldest data 10 second data gets discarded. So I was thinking for this I can use a hopping window of 60 seconds with an advance of 10 seconds.

Comment: That sounds correct. What is the issue? You can use `WINDOW HOPPING (SIZE 60 SECONDS, ADVANCE BY 10 SECONDS)` Cf https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/syntax-reference.html#select (btw: this seems to be a new question :))

Comment: You are right in terms of a new question haha. Created and posted one here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51794596/ksql-hopping-window-accessing-only-oldest-subwindow