# KSQL Hopping Window : accessing only oldest subwindow

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, ksqldb

I am tracking the rolling sum of a particular field by using a query which looks something like this :

```
SELECT id, SUM(quantity) AS quantity from stream \
WINDOW HOPPING (SIZE 1 MINUTE, ADVANCE BY 10 SECONDS) \
GROUP BY id;
```

Now, for every input tick, it seems to return me 6 different aggregated values I guess which are for the following time periods :

```
[start, start+60] seconds
[start+10, start+60] seconds
[start+20, start+60] seconds
[start+30, start+60] seconds
[start+40, start+60] seconds
[start+50, start+60] seconds
```

What if I am interested is only getting the [start, start+60]  seconds result for every tick that comes in. Is there anyway to get ONLY that?

Comment: Should it be `start+70`, `start+80` etc? I don't think that all windows have the same end timestamp :)

Comment: Ah I can see how it is confusing. I meant more in terms of time range of actual data contained. So at the end of first 60 seconds, the data gets spit out would be like :


 Aggregation over the last 60 seconds, 50 seconds, 40 seconds, 30 seconds, 20 seconds and 10 seconds.


Correct?

Comment: Do you mean, when the first record you process has for example timestamp 1005, you get windows `[950,1010), [960, 1020), [970,1030), [980, 1040), [990,1050)`, and `[1000,1060)`? But you only want to get window `[1000,1060)` but no older windows?

Comment: @ Matthias J. Sax. with streams API, how to the get results of window [1000,1060) results only as per your example. is filtering the latest window is the only option? or is there way we can suppress old windows on hopping?

Answer (score 1):

Because you specify a hopping window, each record falls into multiple windows and all windows need to be updated when processing a record. Updating only one window would be incorrect and the result would be wrong.

Compare the Kafka Streams docs about hopping windows (Kafka Streams is KSQL's internal runtime engine): https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#hopping-time-windows

**Update**

Kafka Streams is adding proper sliding window support via KIP-450 (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-450%3A+Sliding+Window+Aggregations+in+the+DSL). This should allow to add sliding window to ksqlDB later, too.

Comment: I get that all the windows need to be updated for the windowing to work correctly but what I am looking for is a way to get only the result from [start, start+60] seconds so I can dump only those updates in a separate topic from the results of windowing. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean -- I guess you can filter -- but why do you want the result of a single window only? It's stream processing and not batch processing for which you would select a certain time range only. Or maybe I miss understand your question.

Comment: How can I get that since the window information itself is not exposed directly in a way that can be easily filtered unless I have some kind of a custom UDF I guess which can pick out the row with minimum window time?

The reason I need this is, is simple. At any point of time I care about what happened in the last 60 seconds only. But when the 60 seconds are up, I don't want all the 60 second data to be discarded, only the last 10 seconds. Hence a 60 second hopping window with an advance of 10 seconds.

Comment: I think we are getting closer to understand each other :) The way KSQL works is, that it maintains all windows in parallel, ie, there is not a single "buffer of records" for one window, and when time progresses, records are removed from the window and the window "shifts". KSQL maintains a "buffer" for all windows in parallel (note, that KSQL does not store the raw records in a "buffer", but maintains the aggregation result per window instead). Because all windows are updated at the same time, you get update records for all windows.

Comment: Note, that KSQL does not "close" windows, and also does not emit a single result per window -- instead, each update to a window is reported immediately. You might want to read this blog post, that explains the runtime model: https://www.confluent.io/blog/watermarks-tables-event-time-dataflow-model/

Comment: Thus, if you expect to get updates for the latest windows only, and only if time progresses, you get updates for the next window, than the answer is "no" -- you cannot do this with KSQL.

Comment: I get that the computation model is built on calculating updates soon as an event happens. What I am looking for simply is every time the n-number of aggregation values get generated because of an incoming event, I want to be able to filter and put one of them in a different topic. I don't need the update to be generated when a new time window begins or anything. 

Sorry I made it so hard to understand.

Comment: I don't think it's possible: the model dictates that all windows are updated and all updates trigger an update output event. Note, that there is WIP to emit only one single final result per window (this feature will increase latency of course, as we need to delay the computation accordingly after a window ended plus some additional delay to address late arriving records). This might be included in CP 5.1 release (no promise).

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation and creating a user defined function to access only the window with collect_list(column).size() = window duration appears to be a promising track.

In the udf use List type to get one of your aggregate base column list of values. Then assess is the formed list size is equal to the hopping window number of period, return null otherwise.

From this create a table selecting data and transforming it with the udf.

Create a table from this latest table and filter out null values on the transformed column.